# Angular SSR without page reload on click links

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to use angular SSR and change pages without reload ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible and it's not linked.

You can use [Angular Routes](https://angular.io/guide/router)

You need to changes the links :

```
<a href="/exempleRoute">My link</a>
```

by :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/exempleRoute']">My link</a>
```